# initialize a list of dictionary values

Tags: python

I'd like to know how to statically initialize a list of dictionaries -- something like this:

Originally, I had a list like this:

```
consumers = ['aserver.foo.com','anotherserver.foo.com',
             'thirdserver.foo.com','lastserver.foo.com']
```

But I'd like to have a structure I can address like this:

```
consumers = [
        'aserver'{
            'hostname'='aserver.foo.com',
            'binddn'=masterbinddn,
            'bindpw'=masterbindpw
            },
        'anotherserver'{
            'hostname'='anotherserver.foo.com',
            'binddn'=masterbinddn,
            'bindpw'=masterbindpw
        }, 
        'athirdserver'{
            'hostname'='athirdserver.foo.com',
            'binddn'=targetbinddn,
            'bindpw'=targetbindpw
        }, 
        'lastserver'{
            'hostname'='lastserver.foo.com',
            'binddn'=targetbinddn,
            'bindpw'=targetbindpw
        }
    ]
```

The idea being that I can do something like:

```
for server in consumers:
    do_something_to_server(server['hostname'], server['binddn'], server['bindpw'])
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree, or just missing something basic?

Comment: So why do you think you cant do it?

Answer (score 5):

The following will create a list of dictionaries:

```
consumers = [
    {
        'hostname': 'aserver.foo.com',
        'binddn': masterbinddn,
        'bindpw': masterbindpw
    },
    {
        'hostname': 'anotherserver.foo.com',
        'binddn': masterbinddn,
        'bindpw': masterbindpw
    }, 
    {
        'hostname': 'athirdserver.foo.com',
        'binddn': targetbinddn,
        'bindpw': targetbindpw
    }, 
    {
        'hostname': 'lastserver.foo.com',
        'binddn': targetbinddn,
        'bindpw': targetbindpw
    },
]
```

You can then iterate over it like so:

```
for server in consumers:
    do_something_to_server(server['hostname'], server['binddn'], server['bindpw'])
```

Comment: This is not syntactically valid.

Comment: @Marcin: Are you sure you're looking at the current version of the answer, and not at some intermediate edit? It works fine in my Python interpreter.

Comment: Yes, it's valid now that you have changed it.

Answer (score 1):

Just take your structure:

```
consumers = {
    'aserver': {
        'hostname':'aserver.foo.com',
        'binddn':masterbinddn,
        'bindpw':masterbindpw
        },
    'anotherserver': {
        'hostname':'anotherserver.foo.com',
        'binddn':masterbinddn,
        'bindpw':masterbindpw
    }, 
    'athirdserver': {
        'hostname':'athirdserver.foo.com',
        'binddn':targetbinddn,
        'bindpw':targetbindpw
    }, 
    'lastserver': {
        'hostname':'lastserver.foo.com',
        'binddn':targetbinddn,
        'bindpw':targetbindpw
    }
}
```

And change the for with:

```
for server in consumers.values():
    do_something_to_server(server['hostname'], server['binddn'], server['bindpw'])
```

Comment: Thx, copy pasted and forgot :D

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you either want a dictionary of dictionaries, or to add another field to your dictionaries to capture the name you have before them in your pseudo-code.

Also, the main problem you have is that you have dictionary syntax wrong. A literal dictionary is:

```
{ 'key': 'value'}

# or

dict(key = 'value')

# not

{'key' = 'value'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use little more efficient `namedtuple` type

```
from collections import namedtuple
server = namedtuple('server', ('hostname','binddn','bindpw'))

consumers = [
    server(
        hostname = 'aserver.foo.com',
        binddn = masterbinddn,
        bindpw = masterbindpw
            ),
    server(
        hostname = 'anotherserver.foo.com',
        binddn = masterbinddn,
        bindpw = masterbindpw
            ),
    server(
        hostname = 'athirdserver.foo.com',
        binddn = targetbinddn,
        bindpw = targetbindpw
            ),
    server(
        hostname = 'lastserver.foo.com',
        binddn = targetbinddn,
        bindpw = targetbindpw
            ),
    ]
```

And your loop changes to:

```
for consumer in consumers:
    do_something_to_server(consumer.hostname, consumer.binddn, consumer.bindpw)
```

Or even:

```
for consumer in consumers:
        do_something_to_server(*consumer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example datastructure is not valid Python: you can't have strings immediately followed by dictionaries.

But to get a simple list of dictionaries, this would work:

```
consumers = ['aserver.foo.com','anotherserver.foo.com',
             'thirdserver.foo.com','lastserver.foo.com']

consumer_dict = [{'hostname': consumer, 'binddn': targetbinddn, 'bindpw': targetbindpw}
                 for consumer in consumers
```